# One Command can get all the IP addresses from a Domains text file

Tags: networking, terminal, command-line, ip, subdomain

As we know, to get any IP for a domain or a Subdomain we use alot of commands, such as:

nslookup
host
ping

But I want to use this one: { dig }

for example:

$ **dig +short [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)**

the IP we'll get :

**142.251.37.196**

NOW...

I want a command ( with using dig or with another command ) that read a Domains_file.txt line by line and get IP by IP and then show me all the IPs

Simply:

**I have a list with 100 domains, and with using one command, I can get 100 IPs, Could you please give me a command like this?**

Sorry for my bad knowledge about the accurate terms I must use

Thanks :)

Comment: "_I can get 100 IPs_" There are only two IPs (Internet Protocols): IPv4 and IPv6. You probably mean IP _addresses_.

Comment: Yes I meant IP Addresses